# django pass a predicate to filter funtion

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.7

I have the following code, as you can see only thing that changes is the function call point__distance_gte or point__distance_lte. Is there a way to externalise this function from calling code.

```
def search():
    if distance == 50:
        jobs = list(Job.objects.filter(point__distance_gte=(ref_pnt, D(**distance_from_point))))
    else:                   
        jobs = list(Job.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(ref_pnt, D(**distance_from_point)))
```

So something like:

```
def search(predicate):
    jobs = list(Job.objects.filter(predicate))
```

Although, I am showing only one filter here but in reality I have chained filters and prefetch conditions attached to the query which makes it ugly if I have to repeat code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `objects.filter` is actually a function, you can pass it `kwargs` just like a normal function. So in your example you could do something like:

```
def search(**kwargs):
    jobs = list(Job.objects.filter(**kwargs))

search(point__distance_gte=(ref_pnt, D(**distance_from_point)))
search(point__distance_lte=(ref_pnt, D(**distance_from_point)))
```